# A Way to Access Subversion in Java

Tags: java, web-services

I am developing a web service in GWT which needs to be able to read and write files on the server.

Initially I was just going to dedicate a directory on the server which will be accessed via the GWT Server. However as this is deployed to Tomcat, I am unsure of the problems that could arise or if it is even possible.

**I would like** a way for the GWT application's server side to have access to a Subversion server. Where files generated on the fly in the GWT Client side are sent to the server, the file is created and commited to subversion. Therefore, should someone want this file (which is a configuration file) they can then have access to it again by checking it out, etc.

Is this possible? Subversion sounds like the ideal solution however I am unsure of the problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaHL is an official part of the Subversion project.
Here is a page describing the basic difference between JavaHL and SVNKit: http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/org.tigris.subclipse.doc/topics/faq_subclipse.html (click "What is an adapter? What is JavaHL?")

Answer (score 2):

There are several Java librarys that provide an API to Subversion Servers. Several years ago I used one, but I can't recall its name, however [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/) is a popular one.